# AVD error in ANDROID

Tags: android-emulator

i'v installed eclipse ,ADT plugins and SDK on my system.once i successfully cnfigured them. but this time ,i got an error when launching te AVD.
**

> invalid command-line parameter:
>   Dev\android-sdk-windows\tools/emulator-arm.exe. Hint: use '@foo' to
>   launch a virtual device named 'foo'. please use -help for more
>   information

**
any one can help me to fix this problem please.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

manoj lasantha

I got the same issue but it has been fixed by changing the path (eclipse>windows>preferences>Andriod SDK Location **C:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk**)

Previously i had this path C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk after changing to above path my problem was fixed. Try this ur issue may fix

Change

SDK Location

C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk

to

**C:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk**

IDE is not allowing Spaces

Comment: yap: thankz rehan. i changed the full path and now my SDK is working properly.